# How to get list of installed input languages (keyboard layouts)?

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard-layout

The questions I saw here is mostly about getting current input layout, but I need list of all installed input layouts.
It's like when we install Windows we choose additional input method for our native language and we usually has 2 of them. And I need to know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (InputLanguage c in System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.Culture.EnglishName);
}
```